# Service uuidd won't start automatically after reboot

Tags: 16.04, services

I'm not proficient in Ubuntu or Linux in general, so I can't figure out this issue I'm experiencing.

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu 16.04 machine with an image from one of our customers. For some reason, on this machine the service "uuidd" fails to start after reboot.

This is the 10th machine I'm setting up with this image, and there has been no issues on the first 9.

If i start the service uuidd with the command "sudo service uuidd start" then it runs without issue until I reboot the machine. After the reboot it won't start up automatically.

I enabled automatic start with the command "sudo update-rc.d uuidd defaults". Another service that I have used that command on, rmmagent, starts up automatically after reboot. It is only the service "uuidd" that won't start on this machine.

I tried the command "systemctl enable uuidd" but it kept asking me for the password to the machines superuser, which I am logged in with.

The only error I see on the machine is that it says "sudo: Could not resolve hostname ". This happens on another machine that I have set up aswell, but that machine struggles with running the service "cups" (even if I start it manually), so I thought that was a different issue alltogether.

Does anyone have any idea what is going?

Best regards,
Marius

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82825/discussion-on-question-by-marius-service-uuidd-wont-start-automatically-after-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that the service only runs when it is in use. On the other nodes where it is ok I am assuming it runs often enough to not stop.

Thanks :)